# Lucee IIS10 - Tomcat 8.5 BonCodeAJP Connector - Generic Connector Communication Error

Tags: tomcat, communication, connector, lucee

I have a Windows 2016 64bit server installation that runs Lucee 5.3.1.102 with Tomcat/8.5.35 with BonCodeAJP Connector.

Everything runs smooth in general and the website has on average between 600k to 1 million user per day. On very rare occasions we get the following error:

```
Generic Connector Communication Error:

Please check and adjust your setup:

Ensure that Tomcat is running on given host and port.

If this is a timeout error consider adjusting IIS timeout by changing
executionTimeout attribute in web.config (see manual).
```

When a browser displays the error, the only way to display again the actual page of the website is to clear all website data. If you only refresh it displays again the error, despite the fact that the website runs now without errors(the error gets displayed once but the error page still displays on the browser no matter how many reloads, so the user thinks that the site is down, till he tries on incognito window or tries on another browser).

So is there any way to change the error page so that it redirects automatically or maybe expire content so that the browser can see the website again?.
Also do you have any idea why this error appears even if it appears on so rare occasions?

Thank you in advance for your help
here is server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
    define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
    Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
-->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
 <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
 -->
 <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
 <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

 <!-- Global JNDI resources
      Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
 -->
 <!-- <GlobalNamingResources> -->
   <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
        UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
   -->
   <!-- <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
             type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
             description="User database that can be updated and saved"
             factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
             pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" /> -->
 <!-- </GlobalNamingResources> -->

 <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
      a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
      so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
      Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
  -->
 <Service name="Catalina">

   <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
   <!--
   <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
       maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
   -->


   <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
        and responses are returned. Documentation at :
        Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
        Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
        APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
        Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
   -->
   <Connector port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443" />
   <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
   <!--
   <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
              port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443" />
   -->
   <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
        This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
        style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
        OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
        documentation -->
   <!--
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
              maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
              clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
   -->

   <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
   <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" keepAliveTimeout="-1" connectionTimeout="121000" packetSize="65530" redirectPort="8443" />


   <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
        every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
        analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
        on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
        Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

   <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
   -->
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="127.0.0.1">

     <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
         /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
         /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
     <!--
     <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
     -->

     <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
          via a brute-force attack -->
     <!-- <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm"> -->
       <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
            resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
            that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
            available for use by the Realm.  -->
       <!-- <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
              resourceName="UserDatabase"/> -->
     <!-- </Realm> -->

     <Host name="127.0.0.1"  appBase="webapps"
           unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

       <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
            Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
       <!--
       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
       -->

       <!-- Access log processes all example.
            Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
            Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
              prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
              pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

   <!-- visit modcfml.org for details on mod_cfml configuration options -->
   <Valve className="mod_cfml.core"
       loggingEnabled="false"
       maxContexts="200"
       timeBetweenContexts="2000"
       scanClassPaths="false"
       sharedKey="8cb4bca1476f6af2ef9e5f548bfdf7c58015ba1fad1adc9818863b8ea2b8af50"
       />
     </Host>

     <!--
       Add additional VIRTUALHOSTS by copying the following example config:
       REPLACE:
       [ENTER DOMAIN NAME] with a domain, IE: "mysite.com"
       [ENTER SYSTEM PATH] with your web site's base directory. IE: /home/user/public_html/ or C:\websites\www.mysite.com\ etc...
   [ENTER DOMAIN ALIAS] with any domain that also points to this same site/directory. You can repeat this tag as often as needed. 
       Don't forget to remove comments!
     -->
     <!--
   EXAMPLE HOST ENTRY:
       <Host name="lucee.org" appBase="webapps">
            <Context path="" docBase="/var/sites/lucee.org" />
        <Alias>www.lucee.org</Alias>
        <Alias>my.lucee.org</Alias>
       </Host>
   
   HOST ENTRY TEMPLATE:
       <Host name="[ENTER DOMAIN NAME]" appBase="webapps">
            <Context path="" docBase="[ENTER SYSTEM PATH]" />
        <Alias>[ENTER DOMAIN ALIAS]</Alias>
       </Host>
     -->

     <!-- ADD NEW HOSTS HERE -->
    <Host name="xxxx.xx" appBase="webapps">
            <Context path="" docBase="C:\xxxxxx" />
           <Alias>xxx.xx</Alias>
       <Alias>www.xxxxx.xx</Alias>
       <Alias>xxxx.xxxxxx.xx</Alias>
       </Host>
   </Engine>
 </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Can you please post server.xml and any AJP properties files you have

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have posted my server.xml

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be hitting a connection limit of some kind. Try adding a timeout for existing connections (so that dead connections get cleared out) and if you've got the memory, try adding more connections. You will need to modify settings in both the BonCode Connector (it uses .NET) and in Tomcat's AJP connector settings. Documentation on how to do this as well as a helpful debugging section can be found here:
http://www.boncode.net/boncode-connector

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just posted server.xml if you have any other hints

Answer (score 0):

Check if the timeout set in the server.xml is less than the timeout set in IIS.

Reference: https://www.boncode.net/connector/webdocs/Tomcat_Connector.htm

To release unused/stuck connections faster you should establish idle timeouts. These have to be set on both Tomcat and IIS sides and they take different shapes. You should ensure that the Tomcat idle timeout is set a value between 61000 and 121000 as a good start. This value should always be larger than the Application Pool Idle Timeout. If not you will encounter “Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.” Errors. For example, the following definition sets the Tomcat timeout to 2 min and 1s when it is idle. Also it is important to set the keepAliveTimeout so Tomcat does not close the connection when it is still active from the client side.

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="1000" connectionTimeout="121000" keepAliveTimeout="-1" packetSize="65536" />
```

You should set the IIS timeout to less than the connectionTimeout in Tomcat. The following shows a 2 minute setting by manipulating the IIS manager advanced settings